# supply custom hashing/equal func to unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have this following code:

```
typedef std::size_t (*hash_func)(const sp_movie& movie);
typedef bool (*equal_func)(const sp_movie& m1,const sp_movie& m2);

typedef std::unordered_map<sp_movie, double, hash_func, equal_func> rank_map;
```

These are my actual functions I want to use in my unordered_map:

```
std::size_t sp_movie_hash(const sp_movie& movie);
bool sp_movie_equal(const sp_movie& m1,const sp_movie& m2);
```

How ever, I can't create a rank_map with my custom hash function and equal function I made.
I don't want to do it using classes for hash and equal, I just want to pass to the unordered_map the functions I've made.

I tried this code:

```
rank_map check (sp_movie, double, sp_movie_hash, sp_movie_equal);
rank_map check (sp_movie_hash, sp_movie_equal);
```

both of them didn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre], and copy-paste the full and complete build output into the question as well. And add comments on the lines in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: @PythonAddict `sp_movie` and `double` are types. How would it make sense to pass them as function argument? Have a look at the [`std::unordered_map` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) and use one that suits your needs.

Comment: On another note, while one is generally not allowed to do anything in the `std` namespace, specializing [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is allowed: `namespace std { template<> class hash<sp_movie> { std::size_t operator()(const sp_movie& movie) { /* TODO: Implementation of hash */ } }; }`. Also, why don't you overload `operator==` for the equivalence operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only suitable constructor is the one that also accepts `bucket_count`. Passing `0` seems to work:

```
rank_map check(0, sp_movie_hash, sp_movie_equal);
```

However, if you don't want to select the hash/equality functions at runtime, you should make them into functors (default-constructible classes). If you don't want to write the classes yourself, you can wrap the functions (surprisingly) in `std::integral_constant`:

```
using rank_map = std::unordered_map<sp_movie, double,
    std::integral_constant<decltype(&sp_movie_hash), sp_movie_hash>,
    std::integral_constant<decltype(&sp_movie_equal), sp_movie_equal>
>;
```

This makes your hash maps default-constructible, and removes the overhead of storing function pointers.